# removing NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users vs all authenticated users and adding domain group instead

Tags: permissions, security

I have a root site collection and under the "Style Resources Readers group" i have the 
    NT AUTHORITY\authenticated and the all authenticated users .

```
Are these the same groups but with different names? I know the is everyone that can logon o your network.

But i would like to use a domain group instead of the NT AUTHORITY\authenticated?
How can i achieve this?

If i remove the group "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated" how can i add it back? When i tried to add another one i couldn't find it :(
```

Anyway the mean question ican't find anywhere is how can i restrict some users on the site collection if i don't want everyone to have access?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Authenticated covers all security types where NT AUTHORITY are only the local domain users, so if you are only using local domains they are the same.

The best way of achieving what you want is with active directory, this will allow you to make custom groups for all the users properly, and to make your own blanket permissions.

Comment: Thanks Hugh.But as I said what do I need to do to assign AD group then.

Comment: This is to much information for me to go into here but take a look at this great screencast and work from there, if you don't know how to do it off the bat, then you will need to read up and learn first. Once you have it's pretty straight forward. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYhI5lEE7Wc

Answer (score 3):

I would advice not to mess up with these settings. The master page library, as well as the style library (and a few other libraries) requires specific permissions to ensure that everyone (even the one with limited access) can still access to the branding / layout ressources. Since it's somehow mandatory to allow anyone to consume these resources (and will not bring a security breach) I would simply not change it. You might bring additional issue that will be very hard to identify / fix if not documented properly (eg: your AD group users are slightly changed, etc.)

Comment: Hi i agree Francois.So which means the only way is if I want to map specific users to a subsite/list  I would have to break the permission and then apply an AD group for example?

Comment: Sure, but you'll do it per web (subsite) / list and you will not have to change these top level libraries. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users and "All Authenticated Users" are one-in-the-same for Active Directory authentication.

Comment: Thanks guys.I have setup some test regarding restricting access to some sub sites and lists.
Basically stopped inheriting from the root site and then gave AD group to specific sub sites,lists etc..